# Swapping from log4net to Serilog using Common.Logging

Tags: log4net, serilog, common.logging

A solution already exists that uses log4net with Common.Logging, 
we have decided we want to swap out log4net and swap in Serilog.

In `App.config`

```
--<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1215">
++<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Serilog.SerilogFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Serilog">
```

Seems easy enough, but then as I continued looking through our existing `App.config` file I came across less obvious areas of transition.

```
--<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
++<section name="serilog" type="Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration, serilog"/><!--Not sure if equivalent-->
```

This change does not seem as obviously right and is really just a shot in the dark. In fact, I'm pretty sure it is wrong.

Then there is the actual config of the rolling file appender:

```
    <log4net>
    <appender name="LM" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}\\Program\Logs\\specificProgram.log" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="5" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5p - %c{1} - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="QuickLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}\\Program\Logs\\QuickLog.log" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="5" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5p - %c{1} - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="LM">
      <level value="TRACE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LM"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="QuickLog">
      <level value="TRACE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="QuickLog"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

I couldn't find any blogs or documentation on swapping from log4net to Serilog that use mainly `App.config` for settings...

In the code behind, we have a pretty simple initialization

```
 if (null == s_logger || null == quick_logger)
        {                
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = MachineConfiguration.DataPath;
            s_logger = CommonLogging.LogManager.GetLogger("LM");
            quick_logger = CommonLogging.LogManager.GetLogger("QuickLog");
        }
```

Serilog also seems to lack a `GlobalContext`, or at least I haven't found the equivalent yet looking through the library.

Is there any mapping of `App.config` changes from log4net to Serilog? or somewhere to look up what the equivalent types or params are between the two libraries?

I know I can't be the first person to do this swap, but I am having trouble finding documentation that matches what we currently have in place.

Comment: In case it helps - Serilog's `<appSettings>` configuration syntax is discussed in: github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings

Comment: FWIW, I think you'd get the best result here by setting up Serilog how you like it from scratch, using its C# API, and then wiring it to Common.Logging/XML config. Mapping concepts 1:1 could lead to a lot of awkwardness, given the substantial differences between the two libraries. HTH!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt thanks so much. That link is definitely helpful. So glad that there is a way to pass variable to the appconfig for changing the path. That was the biggest concern. So relieved. I'll have to reread the doc again tomorrow morning, but tonight I can sleep in peace.